# ASP.NET jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Following script is on ASP.NET page and working fine, but I want to move it into a separate linked .js file, how can I do it?

What do I need to do with ASP.NET control references: 
`<%= txtMessage.UniqueID %>`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //validate contact form
        $("form").validate({
            rules: {
                <%= txtName.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                <%= txtMessage.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 50,
                    maxlength:1000
                },                
                <%= txtEMail.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            messages: {
                <%= txtName.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: "Your name is required",
                    minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required")
                },
                <%= txtMessage.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: "No Message? that's weird...",
                    minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required"),
                    maxlength: jQuery.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters")
                },
                <%= txtEMail.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: "Your email is required",
                    email: "Wrong e-mail address"
                },
            errorClass: "error",
            ShowPopover:false,
            errorElement:"div",
            ignore: []
        });
```

Comment: There is no much you gain from moving the above code to separate js file, because the code is closely tied to the particular page, and it cannot be reuse elsewhere. So, I'll just leave it at the bottom of the aspx page, unless you are aiming for a single js for each aspx page.

Comment: You can make a dyanmic rule list, check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is rendering variables in my page and then create a dynamic rule list:

In Markup:

```
var txtUserName = '<%= txtUserName.UniqueID%>';
var txtEMail = '<%= txtEMail.UniqueID%>';
var txtMessage = '<%= txtMessage.UniqueID%>';
```

In the script file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //validate contact form
    var ruleList = {}
    ruleList[txtUserName] = {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    };
    ruleList[txtMessage] = {
        required: true,
        minlength: 50,
        maxlength:1000
    };
    ruleList[txtEMail] = {
        required: true,
        email: true
    };
    $("form").validate({
        rules: ruleList,
        messages: {
            .....
            },
        errorClass: "error",
        ShowPopover:false,
        errorElement:"div",
        ignore: []
    });
});
```